# Why doesn't the item properties and command history window not open up in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

When I open a print composer in QGIS, all I see is my map. I do not see the item properties or command history. I can add a legend, scale bar, etc., but I can't edit them. I have not had this problem in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click anywhere on the toolbar in the **Composer window**, you should see a similar list of menus like below:

[image: Composer window menus]

Enable the windows you want. The same windows should load up the next time you restart QGIS.